# JavaFX extend Button and add properties through fxml

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I have extended a JavaFX Button like so:

```
public class ExtendedButton extends Button {
    private ObjectProperty<Enum> x;
    public final void setX(Enum value) {
        x.set(value); 
    }
    public final String getX() {
        return x.get()
    }
}

public enum MyEnum{
    A,
    B
}
```

Now i want to be able to use this in my FXML. Something like this:

```
<ExtendedButton fx:id="xButton" x=MyEnum.A />
```

How do i achieve this.

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes I have, can't get it to work for an Enum.

Comment: You should [edit] your question to show what you tried and explain in what way it didn't work.

Comment: I edited the question.

Comment: Presumably you just missed the initialization of `x` when you copied and pasted the code...? And I think you intended to use `ObjectProperty<MyEnum>`.

Comment: No I did not intend to do that. I want to be able to fill it with any enum

Comment: So at least use `Enum<?>`. And you have initialized `x`, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using property elements, instead of attributes, along with the [`fx:constant` attribute](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#constant_elements):

```xml
<ExtendedButton fx:id="xButton" >
    <x><MyEnum fx:constant="A" /></x>
</ExtendedButton>
```

Here's an SSCCE:

ExtendedButton.java

```
package application;

import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;

public class ExtendedButton extends Button {

    public final ObjectProperty<Enum<?>> buttonState = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(ButtonState.NORMAL);

    public final ObjectProperty<Enum<?>> buttonStateProperty() {
        return this.buttonState;
    }


    public final Enum<?> getButtonState() {
        return this.buttonStateProperty().get();
    }


    public final void setButtonState(final Enum<?> buttonState) {
        this.buttonStateProperty().set(buttonState);
    }

    public ExtendedButton() {
        super();
        styleProperty().bind(Bindings.
                when(buttonState.isEqualTo(ButtonState.CRITICAL)).
                then("-fx-base: red;").
                otherwise(""));


    }

}
```

ButtonState.java:

```
package application;

public enum ButtonState { NORMAL, CRITICAL }
```

ExtendedButtonTest.fxml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>
<?import application.ExtendedButton?>
<?import application.ButtonState?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>

<StackPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <padding>
        <Insets top="20" right="20" bottom="20" left="20"/>
    </padding>
    <ExtendedButton text="Test" >
        <buttonState>
            <ButtonState fx:constant="CRITICAL"/>
        </buttonState>
    </ExtendedButton>
</StackPane>
```

ExtendedButtonTest.java:

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ExtendedButtonTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("ExtendedButtonTest.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```